# Authentication basic for Firefox with WebdriverIO

Tags: node.js, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I use WebdriverIO to create my Selenium tests.

I try to pass credentials on my staging website. I have tried some solutions:

- Firefox Profile : doesn't work with WebdriverIO for me, just ok in Java
- User and password in URL like that : `http://user:password@site.com/`

Comment: If there are input fields for username and password, just find those elements and send appropriate strings

Comment: Thx for this answer, 
It's not input fields, it's windows credentials i can't to find elements and setValue on this.

Comment: I have the same issue here, I'm really surprised that this is such a hassle to setup. Did you have any luck in the meantime?

Comment: There was a issue as 'Firefox driver not working with async functions on webdriverio', maybe your issue can be related with that.